# Help, gostaria de add objeto a um arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, herança

Boa tarde pessoal, preciso muito da ajuda de vcs. Faço engenharia de controle e automação e  estou tendo a cadeira de Programação Orientada a Obj.

O problema no cód abaixo, é que não estou sabendo como adicionar os "employees" ao arraylist, gostaria de adicionar das duas formas, tanto com os dados já definidos, como permitindo ao usuário definir. O problema é que quando exibo o arraylist, não aparece corretamente.

Caso esteja muito equivocado, por favor, comentem comigo como posso add de uma forma melhor.

*tentei fazer uma função "createEmployee" mas não consegui implementar ela no cód, nem sei se esta certa.

Gostaria da ajuda de vcs.

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employees extends People {
    public String workCard;
    public String function;
    public static ArrayList<Employees> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    public Employees(String name, String CPF, String RG, String workCard, String function) {
        super(name, CPF, RG);
        this.workCard = workCard;
        this.function = function;
    }

//    public void createEmployee(String name, String CPF, String RG, String workCard, String function){
//        Employees employees = new Employees(name, CPF, RG, workCard, function);
//        System.out.println("New Employee: Name - CPF - RG - WorkCard - Function");
//        System.out.println("New Employee: " + employees.name + " - " + employees.CPF + " - " + employees.RG + " - " + employees.workCard + " - " + employees.function);
//        empList.add(employees);
//    }

    public void printemp() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + CPF);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employees employee = new Employees("José Armando Plano", "273927329", "3463473", "4343344344343", "Armar Planos");
        System.out.println("New Employee: Name - CPF - RG - WorkCard - Function");
        System.out.println("New Employee: " + employee.name + " - " + employee.CPF + " - " + employee.RG + " - " + employee.workCard + " - " + employee.function);
        empList.add(employee);

        String aux = "yes";
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Employee Name:");
            employee.name = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Employee CPF:");
            employee.CPF = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Employee RG:");
            employee.RG = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Employee WorkCard:");
            employee.workCard = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Employee Function:");
            employee.function = reader.nextLine();
            empList.add(new Employees(employee.name, employee.CPF, employee.RG, employee.workCard, employee.function));

            System.out.println("Write 'yes' for more");
            aux = reader.nextLine();
        }while(aux.equals("yes"));

        for (Employees t : empList) {
            t.printemp();
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

1 - Separa a classe `Employees` do método `main` ( `Employees.java` ):

2 - Criar os getters e setters da classe `Employees`

```
public class Employees 
{
    private String WorkCard;

    private String Function;

    public Employees(String WorkCard, String Function){
      this.WorkCard = WorkCard;
      this.Function = Function;
    }

    public void setWorkCard(String WorkCard){
      this.WorkCard = WorkCard;
    }

    public String getWorkCard(){
      return this.WorkCard;
    }

    public void setFunction(String Function){
      this.Function = Function;
    }

    public String getFunction(){
      return this.Function;
    }

}
```

3 - Criar a Lista de `Employees` fora da classe `Employees` dentro da classe `Main`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {  

  private static ArrayList<Employees> Employees = new ArrayList<Employees>();
  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 

    Employees emp1 = new Employees("000.000-Z", "Developer");
    Employees emp2 = new Employees("000.123-X", "Manager");

    Employees.add(emp1);
    Employees.add(emp2);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < Employees.size(); i++){
       System.out.println("WorkCard: " + Employees.get(i).getWorkCard() + " Function:" + Employees.get(i).getFunction());
    }

  }

}
```